# Java: access static final field in JNI

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, android-5.0-lollipop, android-runtime

Is there a way to access a static final field in JNI?

```
public class TryMe {
    public int a = 1;
    public final int b = 2;
    public static int c = 3;
    public static final int d = 4;
}
```

The C++ JNI code:

```
jclass cls = env->FindClass("my/package/TryMe");

jfieldID a = env->GetFieldID(cls, "a", "I"); //OK
jfieldID b = env->GetFieldID(cls, "b", "I"); //OK
jfieldID c = env->GetStaticFieldID(cls, "c", "I"); //OK
jfieldID d = env->GetStaticFieldID(cls, "d", "I"); //Error!
```

The last call returns NULL and fails. Any idea why?

Comment: If it returns null you should use one of the exception methods to *tell* you why.

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED: I've been bitten by proguard.

I initially thought it might be a bug in the android runtime but it isn't. I believe that proguard doesn't know and doesn't care about JNI so it decided to optimize out the "constant". After adding this to proguard.cfg:

```
keep class my.package.TryMe {
    public static final int d;
}
```

the problem has disappeared.

Comment: No doubt, but you still need to check the result of every JNI call, and the initial problem was that you weren't doing that.

Answer (score 0):

After using `javap -p -s TryMe`, does the variable `d` appear like:

> ...
>   public static final int d;
>       descriptor: I 
>   ...

?

If so, then I dont really see a reason why it shouldn't work. What platform are you trying this on? I tried your example with the following code on Arch x86_64 and it works for me:

Test.java:

```
public class Test {
    public int a = 1;
    public final int b = 2;
    public static int c = 3;
    public static final int d = 4;
}
```

ctest.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <jni.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
     JavaVM *jvm;
     JNIEnv *env;

    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options[1];
    options[0].optionString = const_cast<char*>("-Djava.class.path=/home/fishi/Workspace/tmp/");
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

    /* Create the Java VM */
    int res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &vm_args); 

     if (res == JNI_ERR){
         cout << "Fail: Unable to load JVM \t Exit" << endl;
        return 1;
     }
         else if (res == JNI_OK){
         cout << "CreateVM:\t\tJVM loaded successfully!" << endl;
     }

    /* Find class and static field */
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("Test");
    if(cls == NULL)
    {
        cout << "FindClass:\t\tCould not load class!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "FindClass:\t\tLoaded class successfully!" << endl;
    }
    jfieldID field = env->GetStaticFieldID(cls, "d", "I");
    if(field == NULL)
    {
        cout << "GetField:\t\tError!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Success" << endl;
}
```

Makefile:

```
build-jni:
    g++ -g -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/include/linux/ -L/usr/bin/java -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server/ ctest.cpp -ljvm -o ctest

run-jni:
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/bin/java:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server/ ./ctest
```

Output:

> $ make run-jni 
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/bin/java:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server/ ./ctest 
>   CreateVM:     JVM loaded successfully!
>  
>   FindClass:        Loaded class successfully! 
>   Success

Hope this is helpful in some way.